# In Google Docs can the entire background colour for a piece of text be changed?

Tags: google-docs

I know there's highlighting the background of text, but this only applies to the background around the text. Can the entire background be changed in colour so it doesn't look all choppy? I need different backgrounds for different portion of text through out the document, so I can't just change the default from white.

This is how it looks like with highlighting
[image: currently looks like this]
How do you get it like this?
[image: how to get it looking like this?]

Answer (score 43):

1. Select the text
2. Format> Paragraph Styles> Borders and Shading
3. Choose your background color

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google Documents doesn't include in its UI a tool to apply color to the paragraph, cell or table. AFAIK the options available at this time are:

1. to set the page background color.
2. to insert a drawing
3. to insert an image

## 1. Page background color

This is not suitable due it change the color for the whole document.

## 2. Insert a drawing

Google Drawings have tools to insert shapes and text objects. It could be used to create text blocks with the required background color. You could create the Drawing directly from the Google Documents UI, just click `Insert > Drawing...`. One benefit of this method is that the drawing could be easily edited.

[image: Google document with color text blocks]

## 3. Insert an image

You could use an image editor or a editor that allows to save files as images to create the text blocks with the required background color, then insert them to the Google document.

---

- [Page Setup - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183618?hl=en)
- [Insert a drawing into another doc type - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179708?hl=en)
- [Insert an image - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.

Comment: @Celeritas I don't think so. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a 1 cell table as described in this link:

https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-tips-for-working-on-Google-Docs

Then change the cell background color with the text inserted.

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps! We like answers that are "self-contained". A reader shouldn't have to follow a link to get the information they need. Links should be used to supplement answers.

Comment: This answer might not have the ideal presentation but its propsed solution is superior IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

There's two steps required to make your text look like your example and it leaves the text editable without turning it into an image.

1. Drag-select the paragraph you want highlighted.
2. Choose a text highlight color, remembering which one you chose. This option is next to the settings for bold, italic, underline etc.
3. With the text still selected go to Format > Paragraph Styles > Borders and Shading
4. Select the same color for the background color.

As long as both colors are the same it will make one solid block of background color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background color from a Google Doc, save the Google Doc as a Word Doc. Open the document in Word and enable editing on the yellow banner at the top of the document. Then to remove the color background, click on Design > Page Color > No Color. You can resave the document as a Google Doc. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/change the background color by going to File > Page Setup. In the Page Setup dialog box, go to Page Color.